# Merge all columns into one without keeping colnames

Tags: r, reshape

I have this format of dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("text1", "text3"
), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("text1", 
"text2"), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "text1", class = "factor"), 
    col4 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("text2", "text4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

And I would like to merge/combine all columns into one without keeping the column names.

Example output:

```
text1
text2
text1
text2
text3
text1
text1
text4
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277904/how-to-merge-multiple-columns-values-into-one-column) example but it merges the rows.

Comment: Just do `data.frame(newcol = c(t(df)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun thank you very much. Not just it is the answer I was looking. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We transpose the dataset, concatenate it to a `vector` and create a `data.frame` based on that

```
data.frame(newcol = c(t(df)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```